# Как начать использовать susy 3?

Tags: css, node.js, gulp, sass

Добрый день! Учусь верстке. Начал использовать в работу sass. Компиляцию и сборку делаю в связке nodejs 8.1.4 + gulp 3.9.1. Решил попробовать использовать susy 3. Но вот проблемы с его установкой. Пробовал устанавливать через bower, добавил  `@import "../../bower_components/susy/sass/susy";` в основной файл sass. Далее задаю настройки

```
  $susy: (
  columns: 12, 
  container: 940px,
  gutters: 0.25,
  global-box-sizing: border-box,
  debug: (image: show-columns)
  );
```

и собственно класс

```
.content{
    @include span(12);
}
```

в терминале вываливается ошибка

```
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
src\style\main.scss
Error: no mixin named span
Backtrace:
src/style/main.scss:14
on line 14 of src/style/main.scss
>>     @include span(12);
-------------^
```

попробовал установить с помощью npm `npm install susy --save-dev`

в галп добавил задачу: `.pipe(sass({includePaths: ['node_modules/susy/sass']}))`

в основной файл sass делаю `@import 'susy'`

в консоль вываливается ошибка

```
Error in plugin 'sass'
    Message:
    src\style\main.scss
    Error: File to import not found or unreadable: susy.
       Parent style sheet: D:/basic-template/src/style/main.scss
        on line 4 of src/style/main.scss
    >> @import 'susy';
```

Ссылка на [gulp](https://github.com/scarfase/basic-template/blob/master/gulpfile.js)

Ну собственно что я делаю не так? Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 1):

Большинство информации в интернете по susy 2.0. А через "npm install susy" ставиться новейшая версия susy 3.0, которая вышла чуть больше месяца назад и в которой сильно поменялся синтаксис как конфига, так и самих функций. Если кратко, то миксинов больше нет совсем. Стартовый конфиг выглядит примерно так:

```
    $susy: (
      'columns': susy-repeat(12),
      'gutters': 0.25,
      'spread': 'narrow',
      'container-spread': 'narrow',
    );
```

Подробнее в официальной [документации по 3й версии](http://oddbird.net/susy/docs/a-config.html).

Comment: Ну в любом случае мне надо как то подключить этот модуль. Вот как это сделать?

Comment: Если вы установили модуль через npm, то просто в начало вашего scss файла включаете:

        `@import "node_modules/susy/sass/susy";
        @import "node_modules/susy/sass/plugins/svg-grid";`

Пути при необходимости замените на свои в зависимости от того, где у вас находится  папка node_modules.